# Better performance on Azure Websites with 2 Small Instances or 1 Medium

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

With Azures recent introduction of the Basic Tier, I have a question on performance:

I run a small website that receives around 30 000 hits a month. It runs great on Azure Websites with a SQL Azure DB.

Assuming it is similarly and my generous MSDN credits can afford it: (i.e. free)

Basic and Standard appear to be the same in terms of CPU size and memory etc. (this is down to the size of the Instance that you select, eg. Small/Medium/Large). I don’t need 50 gigs of space and the extra features such as Staging/Backups so I have dropped to Basic. This means I can now afford to either:

1)  Upgrade to 2 Small Instances    (2 x 1 Core, 1.75 GB)
2)  Upgrade to 1 Medium Instance    (1 x 2 Cores, 3.5 GB)

Which will be more performance (in terms of average responsiveness for the user when they browse the site)? I have tried both and they appear about the same. I would guess that 2 instances would handle more load better and 1 medium would handle more CPU processing better?

Comment: You tried both and they performed the same. That's as good a guess as anyone, right? This is going to be app-specific, depending on your memory and cpu needs. Different behavior in failure case though, if a vm crashes (one scenario has temporary diminished performance, one has temporary outage).

Comment: Yes, I was kind of hoping for not a guess ;)  So are you confirming my assumption with the last statement - 1 instance might be faster but less redundant than 2 smaller instances? I guess my point is... there's really not a whole lot of documentation or FAQs on making these kind of decisions.

Comment: This is typically an architectural decision. And, with cloud architectures, since you don't have to make a long-term commit to hardware, it's often better to work with the smallest vm size that properly runs your software (based on cpu, RAM, etc.), then scale out to handle load and high-availability. Again, no magic rule - this would be dependent on your specific app needs. That's why it's difficult to post an answer here, since it will likely just be opinion-based.

Comment: Hmmm - Ok, thanks. I'm gonna leave it on 1 Medium Instance as I will assume that 2 Smalls will not be faster than 1 Small (it would just be more redundant). By that logic, Medium would be faster than 1 OR 2 Smalls. If anyone knows otherwise or can point me at any documentation that explains these settings, please do.

Comment: To clarify: If an app runs fine in a Small, then Medium is not faster than two smalls. If you spread your traffic between two smalls, you should have equivalent performance (same basic machine spec, right?). If you "need" medium, go with medium. Some apps are memory- or cpu-intensive.

Comment: But David, surely 1 Medium runs faster than 1 Small?  (I have free credits so can choose medium or small)

Comment: This is really turning into a discussion, so I'll make this my last comment: Not all apps take advantage of multiple cores (and a medium simply has twice the memory and one extra core over small). If you don't need those resources for a given task, then you won't see a noticeable difference in speed. You may notice more transactions being handled in parallel (which is what you'd expect), and you'd also see the same type of scaling with a pair of small machines. If you have, say, a rendering app that requires ram, then yes, you need bigger vm's. So... benchmark your app. Then you'll know.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is exactly the kind of information I was after.

Comment: I've actually done a lot of load testing on exactly this scenario, and we got better results using fewer instances on a larger app.  Some of the reasons I found were with multiple instances, I could run more tests, but then the DB became a bottleneck, so you would have to scale up accordingly as well.  We also opened an Azure ticket (on something unrelated) but we had reliability issues on 5 mediums, and they said to use 3 large instead.